# Not Able to generate geo_point field with geo_point data type Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to load data from mysql table ES index using logstash. I'm able to load the data into ES but the location field mapping is not not coming as geo_point type. Its showing as keyword type. So that I'm not able to query on geo_point field.

Any help what is the issue? ES version: 6.7.0

This is my `template.json` file:

```
{
    "settings" :
    {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "codec": "best_compression",
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "index.translog.flush_threshold_size": "2g",
        "bootstrap.mlockall": true,
        "indices.fielddata.cache.size": 25%
    },
    "mappings":
    {
            "_doc" :
            '|            "dynamic_templates":
              [
                  {
                      "message_field": {
                        "path_match": "message",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                          "type": "text",
                          "norms": false
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "string_fields": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                          "type": "text",
                          "norms": false,
                          "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
              ],
"properties" : {
                "@timestamp": {
                     "type": "date"
                },
                "@version": {
                     "type": "keyword"
                },
                "location": {
                     "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "lat" : { "type" : "keyword", "index" : "not_analyzed","index_options" : "docs" },
                "lon" : { "type" : "keyword", "index" : "not_analyzed","index_options" : "docs" }
              }
            }
    }
}
```

logstash.conf fileinput

```
{
        jdbc {
                ..........
    }
}
filter
{
    mutate {
        convert => { "lon" => "float" }
        convert => { "lat" => "float" }
        rename => {
            "lon" => "[location][lon]"
            "lat" => "[location][lat]"
        }
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "host:80"
        index => "my_index"
        manage_template => "false"
        document_type => "_doc"
        template_name=>"template.json"
        document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you get when running `GET my_index`?

Comment: Also set `manage_template => "true"` otherwise the template won't be loaded

Comment: GET my_index-> Gives 
"location" : {
            "properties" : {
              "lat" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "lon" : {
                "type" : "float"
              }
            }
          }

Comment: Yes, see my answer below, your template is not being applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing `manage_template => true` and you can also add `template_overwrite => true` just to make sure the template is overridden:

```
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "host:80"
        index => "my_index"
        manage_template => "true"             <---- change this
        template_overwrite => true            <---- also add this
        document_type => "_doc"
        template_name=>"template.json"
        document_id => "%{id}"
  }
```